# Emailing with Mailboxer gem in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailboxer

I've setup my site with Mailboxer to create an in-site messaging system. Now I'd like to implement the email functions of Mailboxer so that when a message is sent in my site, the user will also receive an email notifiying them.

I've searched for documentation, though there doesn't seem to be any for setting up the email side of things. So far, I've taken the mailer classess from the gem's `app/mailer/` directory, and put them in my `app/mailer/` directory, inside of their mailboxer folder. (`app/mailer/mailboxer/`). Now I'm not sure how to make use of the methods in these mailers.

Here are the controllers that I've setup for insite messaging, which are working fine:

**Messages Controller:**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

    # GET /message/new
    def new
        @request = Request.find(params[:request])
        @message = current_user.messages.new
        @user = @request.user
    end

    def reply
        @conversation ||= current_user.mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
    end

    # POST /message/create
    def create
        @user = User.find(params[:user])
        @body = params[:body]
        @subject = params[:subject]
        current_user.send_message(@user, params[:body], params[:subject])
        flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent!"
        redirect_to :conversations
    end
end
```

**Conversations Controller:**

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    helper_method :mailbox, :conversation

    def index
        @conversations ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox.all
    end

    def reply
        current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, :subject))
        redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
    end


    def trashbin
        @trash ||= current_user.mailbox.trash.all
    end

    def trash
        conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
        redirect_to :conversations
    end

    def untrash
        conversation.untrash(current_user)
        redirect_to :back
    end

    def empty_trash
        current_user.mailbox.trash.each do |conversation|
            conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(:deleted => true)
        end
        redirect_to :conversations
    end

    private

    def mailbox
        @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
    end

    def conversation

        @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
    end

    def conversation_params(*keys)
        fetch_params(:conversation, *keys)

    end

    def message_params(*keys)
        fetch_params(:message, *keys)
    end

    def fetch_params(key, *subkeys)
        # debugger
        params[key].instance_eval do
            # debugger
            case subkeys.size
                when 0 then
                    self
                when 1 then
                    self[subkeys.first]
                else
                    subkeys.map { |k| self[k] }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I tried using the `new_message_email` message_mailer function in my messages_controller's `create` method, like this:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user])
    @body = params[:body]
    @subject = params[:subject]
    current_user.send_message(@user, params[:body], params[:subject])
            new_message_mailer(@subject, @user)
    flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to :conversations
end
```

but it's giving me the error `undefined method 'new_message_email' for #<MessagesController:...>`, so apparently I don't know what I'm doing. Could anyone please give me an of what I need to do to set this up? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even I have the same issue. Were you able to setup your application to send email?

Comment: I ended up paying someone on Fiverr $25 to do it for me. Though I was more of a noob at the time and might be able to figure it out now; I'll try and get back to you about it.

Comment: Have you had any luck?